# Visual Studio - Xamarin Forms app - Unable to set up Automatic Provisioning for certificates

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Brand new PAID Developer Account - received confirmation of set up from Apple about a week ago.

Trying to set up either Automatic OR Manual Provisioning for certificates but getting an error.

I've tried from both Visual Studio 2019 (16.10.4) on Windows, and from Visual Studio for Mac (8.10.6 Build 10).

Xcode on the Mac is version 12.5.

## From within Visual Studio

### Attempting to set Automatic Provisioning

> Automatic Provisioning Failed.

```
Resolving certificate...
Fetching valid and locally installed signing identities...
Syncing certificates for "John Doe" team...
Saving Apple Development certificates...
Automatic Provisioning failed: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
```

[image]

### Attempting Manual Provisioning ("Create Certificate")

#### On Windows

[image]

#### On Mac

[image]
[image]

As I said, I have tried this from within both VS for Mac and Windows, with same result.

I've tried deleting the reference to my development account, and re-entering it, but it made no difference.

I've also logged in to my developer account within apple.com to check that all agreements have agreed to, and everything looks fine to me.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: Here are suggestions for you to solve the problem:
1. Delete all the Provisioning profiles in path ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles.
2. Login your apple account in Xcode - Preference - Accounts , click Download Manual Profiles ,and check valid certificate lists with clicking Manage Certificates.
3. Download the Certificates and corresponding Provisioning profiles separately for your main App and Extension , and click to install.
4. Check if the Provisioning profile is available in Xcode.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your ideas. But there are no existing profiles on either my Windows or Macs machines. I have since included screenshots from Visual Studio (Mac and Windows) which may help.

Comment: I would like to know if %localappdata%\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Certificates has a certificate

Comment: Do you have an iOS device selected and connected? If you do, then, you should get IDE logs after the issue occurs to see if that reveals any more info. For the quickest way to fix problem, you should try manual provisioning using Apple's developer web portal. In this case you would need to download and install the certificate to the Mac which will add it to the keychain. You also need to register any iOS devices you want to deploy to for development purposes in Apple's web portal. Also you should create a manual App ID (wildcard or explicit).